# ExoPlayer background audio with foreground video?

Tags: android, audio, video, service, exoplayer

I'm using ExoPlayer for media playback in an Android application.

When you open up a video in my app, I want the video to be visible while you can hear the audio - like any normal media player.

However when you close the app, I want the audio to continue to play in a background service with a notification for playing, pausing, and restarting the content.

I know that I can get the audio to behave this way if the ExoPlayer is instantiated within a Service. However in order for the video to be visible, the ExoPlayer instance must be passed to the PlayerView and the PlayerView must run on the UI thread.

If the ExoPlayer instance is defined within a Service, and runs on the Service's worker thread, while the PlayerView is defined within an Activity and runs on the UI thread, then how can I pass the ExoPlayer instance to the PlayerView? AIDL is limited to primitive types (String, long, boolean, etc) so it doesn't seem possible.

I would prefer if audio didn't stop and restart when you closed the app (as would be the case if I had two separate players - one in the Service and one in the UI thread). I would like the Service to handle all downloading of media, decoding, and audio playback and I would like to somehow bind to the service to display the decoded frames that are kicked back from ExoPlayer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I noted in the question, you can't pass the ExoPlayer instance to both the PlayerView and the Service -- but if the ExoPlayer instance is accessible via a Singleton, then both the PlayerView and Service will be able to access it directly using the Singleton's methods.

The issue I ran into is that when I created the application this way, the Singleton (and ExoPlayer instance) lived in the application's process space -- not in the foreground service. Therefore when the application was killed, the service continued to run but its ExoPlayer instance was destroyed (the notification remained active, but audio cut out)

I'm not sure yet how to keep the Singleton in the service's process space. It may simply be a matter of ensuring the service accesses the Singleton before the application does.